# Using Application Insights with Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, windows-10-iot-core

There is a great guide for using Application Inights in Windows Apps: [Application Insights for Windows Phone and Store apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/).

Any best practices for using Application Insight with Windows 10 IoT Core? I see an interesting usage for using Application Insigts as a easy to use event logging mechanism to monitor headless App running state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my finding.

Don't use: `WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync("1234567-1111-1234-1234-1234567890ab");` to initialize Application Insights as this will crash the IoT App.

I used somwthing like this instead:

```
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral _defferal;

    internal static TelemetryClient TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();


    public StartupTask()
    {
        TelemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "1234567-1111-1234-1234-1234567890ab";

    }

    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
        taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;

        _defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        ... [insert your code]...
    }
}
```

To use the Application insights I just use `StartupTask.TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("Some event")` or some of the other App Insight methods wherever I need too.

Comment: how was it crashing?  you might be able to use the other initializer method, `WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync( "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   WindowsCollectors.Metadata
   | WindowsCollectors.PageView
   | WindowsCollectors.Session
   | WindowsCollectors.UnhandledException);` and removing some of those collectors to see which one is the problem?